# How to sharpen blue LED voltage-to-current knee at 3.0 V?

Tags: led, bjt, zener

I want to use blue LED as simple 3.0V nominal vs brownout indicator. It will be mounted on tiny proto board and will be plugged into rails or other various parts of breadboard. I want to make same plugs for 4.9V and 1.8V.

The LED is bright at 5mA 3.2V. And it is still visible at about 2.2 V but very dim. I want it to shut completely at about 2.8V and stay bright at 2.95..3.1V.

How can I improve sharpness (steepness) of threshold with any amount of simple BJTs, resistors ?
Thank you.

Answer: as accepted, but with more details for 95% sharp threshold near 3.0V.
[image]

[image]

Green trace is jump of output voltage on collector of T2, when power is reaching 3V -5%. 
Blue trace is a normal diode + resistor current for comparison. Red trace is power voltage. Scale is 3.3V for voltages. For simplicity, consider milliseconds are percents of voltage nominal.

Update after physical implementation: The resulting threshold is 2.92V=dim, 2.96V=bright. The resistors were slightly changed (no 91K in stock), so R1=23.5K(2x47K parallel), R2=2K, R3=82K, R5=270), LED=blue smt one from dead HP laptop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't mention it but the best solution is a comparator, which is easy to set the toggle level of.

A BJT counterpart is the transistor Schmitt-trigger:

[image]

[This website](http://www.johnhearfield.com/Eng/Schmitt.htm) has detailed examples of the required calculations for the thresholds.

A third option is a simple NPN transistor with a 1:4 resistor divider, so that above 2.8 V in the transistor conducts and switches on the LED. The higher the HFE the sharper the corner point. That has nothing to do with the transistor's Ic-Vbe curve, but because of the higher HFE you'll reach the point where the current limiting resistor takes over more quickly. Without the current limiting resistor you would still have a current that varies with the voltage, giving a transition region you don't want.

If you want you can make a Darlington of 2 [BC337-40](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/BC817_BC817W_BC337.pdf)s, that should give you an HFE of at least 62000. Don't forget to adjust the divider to 1:2 for that.

Comment: 'The higher the HFE the sharper the corner point' Why is that?

Comment: @m.Alin - Added this to my answer: "That has nothing to do with the transistor's Ic-Vbe curve, but because of the higher HFE you'll reach the point where the current limiting resistor takes over more quickly."

Answer (score 1):

Voltage detector ICs are very cheap and will do exactly what you want - just search digikey,Mouser etc. for "Voltage Detector" and you will find plenty. Some have inbuilt delays to extend the output, which will make very short dips visible